# Return a specific string from a Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, next.js

I am writing a React/Next.js application and I am using what3words to map items to a location. My code takes in the what3words address, converts it to coordinates, and then is supposed to show the location on a Mapbox map.

```js
const Item = () => {
  const location = "daring.lion.race";
  const api = require("@what3words/api");
  api.setOptions({ key: "my_api_key" });
  const data = api.convertToCoordinates(location).then((value) => {
    return value;
  });

  const [coords, setCoords] = useState();

  async function getCoords() {
    const jason = await data;
    console.log(jason);
    setCoords(jason);
  }

  getCoords();

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: 1000,
    height: 400,
    latitude: coords.coordinates.lat,
    longitude: coords.coordinates.lng,
    zoom: 16,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMapGL
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11"
        mapboxApiAccessToken="my_api_key"
        {...viewport}
       ></ReactMapGL>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The what3words API returns a promise:

```json
{
  "country": "GB",
  "square": {
    "southwest": {
      "lng": -0.12552,
      "lat": 51.508328
    },
    "northeast": {
      "lng": -0.125477,
      "lat": 51.508355
    }
  },
  "nearestPlace": "London",
  "coordinates": {
    "lng": -0.125499,
    "lat": 51.508341
  },
  "words": "daring.lion.race",
  "language": "en",
  "map": "https://w3w.co/daring.lion.race"
}
```

I'm trying to the coordinates out of the promise to put in the viewport, and it doesn't work. I'm using ReactMapGL (http://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/) to display the Mapbox map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCoords` is *asynchronous*, so you can't invoke it and then immediately try to use its result.  Outside of the asynchronous operation, you can set your initial state to some default values:

```
const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
  width: 1000,
  height: 400,
  latitude: 0,  // default value
  longitude: 0, // default value
  zoom: 16,
});
```

Then in your asynchronous operation, after the data is available, you can update the state with those values (just as you already do with the `coords` state):

```
async function getCoords() {
  const jason = await data;
  console.log(jason);
  setCoords(jason);
  // here:
  setViewport({
    ...viewport,
    latitude: jason.coordinates.lat,
    longitude: jason.coordinates.lng,
  });
}
```

Note that the component will briefly render with the default values before re-rendering with the updated values after the asynchronous operation completes.  If this isn't desired then you can conditionally render based on state as well.  Perhaps something like:

```
return (
  <div>
    {
      viewport.latitude === 0 ?
      'Please wait...' :
      <ReactMapGL
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11"
        mapboxApiAccessToken="my_api_key"
        {...viewport}
      ></ReactMapGL>
    }
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, it logs `jason` to the console correctly but then reports an error that `coords` is **undefined**. I tried it without `setCoords` and just using `jason.coordinates.lat` and `jason.coordinates.lng`, but it still returns **undefined**. Any clues?

Comment: @edapm: That was my mistake, I forgot that setting state is asynchronous too.  I’ve updated the code.  Instead of relying on coords on that line, the data you want is in jason.  (Which means you might not need the coords state at all if you only ever use the viewport state.)

Comment: I still get this error:  ```TypeError: can't access property "coordinates", jason is undefined```. It console.logs ``jason``, but then it becomes undefined before ```setViewport```.

Comment: @edapm: Which line gives that error?  You said jason was successfully logging to the console on the line right before we use it.

Comment: The line after `{...viewport}`, `latitude: jason.coordinates.lat`.

Comment: @edapm: That’s the last line in the function, there is no line after that.  Or do you mean on that line?  What did jason log to the console if it’s undefined?  It sounds like there’s a mistake in the debugging here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228698/discussion-between-edapm-and-david).